# Symfony2: Storing users, roles, role hierarchy, and access controls in database

Tags: symfony, acl, hierarchy, roles

I've been working with Symfony (2.x) for the first time and I had some questions regarding the definition of roles, role hierarchy, and how they can be assigned to individual users.

I was interested in storing the roles and role hierarchy in a database (rather than security.yml); however, I cannot find any documentation supporting this.  Is this advisable?

I was interested in having an admin module that can add new roles and define role hierarchies; however, having the admin module modify security.yml or some other config file seems like a bad idea.

This obviously would require that the ACLs can be stored in a database as well.

- Does anyone have any tips or documentation that might help with this?
- Is it a bad idea, performance wise?

I've been successful implementing this with Zend Framework in the past and was hoping to do the same with Symfony2.

Comment: I see there are bundles available which jointly can do this job. FOSUserBundle, SonataAdminBundle, SonataUserBundle (which works on top of FOSUserBundle). I am also starting to develop same in symfony first time. Please share your experience.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you might want to have a look at [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Answer (score 4):

**The solution:**

The following cookbook entry is about storing/retrieving users and roles to/from the database
"How to load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)"
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

To make the long story short, your `role` and `user` entity classes have to implement [RoleInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleInterface.html) and [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) / [AdvancedUserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html) and you have to make some changes to your `security.yml`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to put the roles in the db, and map it using a many-to-many relation.  Then build some admin on the roles.  I wrote how to change the User to use m2m roles at http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities.  I haven't got as far as the role hierarchy so that is still stored in the config.