# Are eventlisteners in Symfony the correct way to implement pages where a superadmin can emulate other users?

Tags: php, symfony

I have been working through [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)  tutorial in the Symfony documentation with the aim of building superuser pages for a sport club website. To give some perspective:

- The site has two pages that both the user and superuser can **edit**: "Parent details", "Student details"
- The site has two pages that the user can **view** and the superuser can **edit**: "Payments" and "Competition results"
- The superuser has access to a few extra fields in the database that are hidden from normal users (eg text comments on payment status and notes on parents/students)

I am trying to put together the superuser pages with a select box in the navbar across each page so that the superuser can select a regular user of whichever page they are and quickly switch between users that they want to simulate and make updates to.

However I wanted to check if this is the correct way to go about it or if I'm going about it the wrong way (eg I'm now wondering if I should some how be managing this this through session management and FOSUserBundle?)

**Update: Just for the sake of clarity...**

...When the superuser is 'simulating' a regular user, the select boxes/options in the menu should still only return the values related to that user (eg, the names of their child/children in the club and their schedule for each sport they attend)

Comment: Add the php tag as well

Comment: Are you talking about impersonating an user? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

Comment: Thanks @Cerad - that looks perfect...I'm glad I asked now :) I just tried adding `switch_user: true` to my main firewall in security.yml but when I try to load a route (such as `http://localhost:8000/students?_switch_user=parentusername1) I just get returned `Access denied, the user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me.`. Do you know what the problem could be still?

Comment: Not really.  Of course you need the switch user role added and to logout and then back in again.  Otherwise, all I can suggest is to follow the example carefully.

Comment: Thanks again @Cerad - and happy new year :) I hadn't created the `switch_user` role...! Should this only be used for testing during development or is safe enough to use in production?

Comment: I use it in production all the time.  Often to help troubleshoot problems that an individual user might have.  I am not a security expert but I do know that the security component has been formally audited.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach to create ACL in Symfony 3 Doc.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Refer this for `Symfony 2` Answer:
[Symfony2: Storing users, roles, role hierarchy, and access controls in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178862/symfony2-storing-users-roles-role-hierachy-and-access-controls-in-database)

ACL Sample GitHub Repos:
https://github.com/GoDisco/AclTreeBundle
https://github.com/wemakecustom/symfony-acl-bundle

Comment: Thanks @Venkatraman - that looks very interesting...I'll definitely take time to read through it properly but as it says in the page itself "...it may be overkill..." for the small use case I have

Comment: @Bendy, Added Repos for you to jump quickly to ACL